# Copy DataTable.Rows to DataRow[]. Faster way then Select() with the same functionality?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dataset, asp.net-4.0

I have now a problem with a very old system of ours. (!*It is more then 7 years old and I have no budget and resources to make bigger change in the structure, so the decision to improve the old logic as many as we can.*!)

We have an own written gridcontrol. Basically it is like a normal ASP.NET grid, you can add, change, delete elements.

The problem is that the grid has a `BindGrid()` method, where for further usage, the rows of the datasource table copied into a `DataRow[]`. I need to keep the `DataRow[]`, but I would like to implement the best way to copy the source from the the table into the array.

The current solution:

```
DataRow[] rows = DataSource.Select("1=1", SortOrderString);
```

As I experienced so far, if I need to get a specified sort, that could be the best way (I'm also interested if it has a quicker way or not.)

BUT there are some simplified pages, where the SortOrder is not needed.

So I could make two method one for the sort order and one for without.
The real problem is the second one:

```
 DataRow[] rows = DataSource.Select("1=1");
```

Because it is very slow. I made some test and it is kind of **15 times slower** then the CopyTo() solution:

```
DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[DataSource.Rows.Count];
DataSource.Rows.CopyTo(rows,0);
```

I would like to use the faster way, BUT when I made the tests some old function simply crashed. It seems, there is an other difference, what I only noticed now: 
**The Select() gets the rows like the RowChanges are accepted.**

So if I deleted a row, and I do not use the `AcceptRowChanges()` (*I can't do that unfortunately*), then with `Select("1=1")` the row is in the `DataSource` but not in the `DataRow[]`.

With a simple `.CopyTo()` the row is there, and that is a bad news for me.

**My questions are:**

1) Is the Select("1=1") the best way to get the rows by the RowChanges? (I doubt a bit, because it is like 6 year old part)

2) And if 1) is not, is it possible to achieve a faster way with the same result than the .Select("1=1") ?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a very basic test app, what I used for speedtesting:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");

dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ID"] = i;
    row["Name"] = "Name" + i;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();

/*DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[dt.Rows.Count];
dt.Rows.CopyTo(rows,0);*/

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - start);
```

Comment: You can call `Select` without an argument: `DataRow[] allRows = DataSource.Select();` That would be for sure more efficient than `"1=1"` since that applies a pointless `RowFilter`. Another way is using `Linq-To-DataSet` to order and filter the `DataTable`. That is not more efficient but more readable and maintanable.

Comment: And is that faster? If yes can you give an answer with some explanation, I'm curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Select` without an argument: `DataRow[] allRows = DataSource.Select();` That would be for sure more efficient than `"1=1"` since that applies a pointless `RowFilter`.

Another way is using [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to order and filter the `DataTable`. That isn't more efficient but more readable and maintainable.

I have yet no example or measurement, but it is obvious that a [`RowFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) with `"1=1"` is more expensive than none. `Select` is implemented in this way:

```
public Select(DataTable table, string filterExpression, string sort, DataViewRowState recordStates)
{
    this.table = table;
    this.IndexFields = table.ParseSortString(sort);
    this.indexDesc = Select.ConvertIndexFieldtoIndexDesc(this.IndexFields);
    // following would be omitted if you would use DataSource.Select() without "1=1"
    if (filterExpression != null && filterExpression.Length > 0)
    {
        this.rowFilter = new DataExpression(this.table, filterExpression);
        this.expression = this.rowFilter.ExpressionNode;
    }
    this.recordStates = recordStates;
}
```

If you want to be able to select also the rows that are currently not accepted, you can use the overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84.aspx):

```
DataRow[] allRows = DataSource.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows | DataViewRowState.Deleted);
```

This will select all rows inclusive the rows that are deleted even if `AcceptChanges` was not called yet.

Comment: Ok I tested it, and I'm surprised: a Select() is not really much faster then the Select("1=1"), however it is stupid anyway to use the "1=1" there. By 10000 rows, with "1=1" the result is 15-16 ms, without is 15. Comparing copyTo which is <1 ms. BUT + 1, becuase it is already better a bit :)

Comment: @AndrásOttó: I've edited my answer to answer this _"The Select() gets the rows like the RowChanges are accepted."_

Comment: Tim: Sure,I have a very very basic test app for this. I update my question with that. (question is updated)

Comment: @AndrásOttó: Ok, but how long is `DateTime.Now-start` for you? On my pc it's only `00:00:00.0230013` (23 milliseconds).